# Getting ‘404 Not Found Nginx’ while trying to visit WordPress post

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a NodeJS app deployed in the root of my domain (example.com) and I'm struggling for the last 7 days to add a blog in a subdirectory (example.com/blog). Even though I have set it up but I think there is some issue with Nginx config as I can't access the blog posts (blog homepage is accessible). It is also worth mentioning that I CAN access the posts if I set Permalinks to Plain in Wordpress settings, which I don't want because of SEO.

If I look at error logs then I can see this:

```
2022/09/02 15:43:43 [error] 86838#86838: *6 "/var/www/html/example.com/blog/advantages-of-social-media-2/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 142.52.23.144, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /blog/advantages-of-social-media-2/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/blog/"
```

Wordpress installation is located in `/var/www/html/example.com/blog` but in the config I have not added `/blog` but I can still access the blog homepage. And if I add it, then I can't access it anymore.

I tried like a million different solutions but nothing seems to be working. Someone please help me out. I'm going crazy over this. I even posted in official Nginx community, Wordpress community, Reddit and couple more places but nothing so far. Please HELP!

Here's the full Nginx config without the SSL statements:

```
server {

       server_name example.com;
       return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;    

}

server {

        server_name www.example.com;

        # NodeJS App
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # Wordpress Blog
        location /blog {

                access_log /var/log/nginx/blog_access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/blog_error.log;

                root /var/www/html/example.com;
                index index.php;

                # Add a trailing slash if missing
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite [^/]$ $uri/ permanent;
                }
                
                # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                # try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

                location ~ \.php {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        # Change this to your fpm socket
                        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DocumentRoot (Apache terminology). Understand this.

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) --> /x/x/x/main-application-document-root
[www.example.com/blog/](http://www.example.com/blog/) --> y/y/y/y/blog-application-document-root

On top of this, you need to trace this through logically step by step (and re-trace your steps!). What is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) getting routed through to as the first interceptor. What is handling this request by default? What does it need to do next?  How does it direct traffic etc.

In most cases in Apache land, if you know where the place a .htaccess file and how to configure it, then you can achieve this outcome. Keeping the technologies separate, while appearing for SEO purposes that everything is running under a single domain.

As with everything, it all depends on your setup.

Ultimately it seems you want some form of logic "somewhere" which says;

if(URI startswith '/blog/')
then send to serverXRunningWordPressAsAReverseProxy

Hope that gives you a pointer to help to trace this through to figure out what you need to configure and where.

Comment: Ummm thanks for your suggestion but I don't think I can fix this with this basic knowledge of mine on Nginx.

Comment: What do you not understand @Zak ? Add another comment and I'll see if I can point you in the right direction.